# Change chartjs data according to selected department

Tags: javascript, laravel, chart.js

I have some graphs which I want to be able to change according to the selected department, but I can't make this happen.

[image: Graphics and select]

Right now I am fetching the data from a controller as follows:

```
public function get_products_by_department(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->ajax()) {

        $dep = $request->departamento;
        
        $articulos = Articulo::whereHas('detalleventas', function($q) use($dep){
            $q->whereHas('venta', function($k) use($dep){
                $k->whereHas('cliente', function($o) use($dep){
                    $o->where('departamento', $dep);
                });
            });
        }
        )->with(['detalleventas' => function($q) use($dep){
            $q->whereHas('venta', function($k) use($dep){
                $k->whereHas('cliente', function($o) use($dep){
                    $o->where('departamento', $dep);
                });
            });
        }])->get();

        $artdep = [];
        foreach ($articulos as $articulo) {
            $artdep[] = ['label' => $articulo->nombre, 'data' => count($articulo->detalleventas)];
        };


        $artdep = array_reverse(array_sort($artdep, 'data'));
        $artdep = array_slice($artdep, 0, 6);  
         
        return response()->json($artdep);
    }
}
```

My intention is that in `->where('departamento', 'Administración');` I can place a $department, so that the department that is selected in the select is the one that filters the data of the graphs.

My graph code is:

```
const config = {
      type: 'doughnut',
      data: {
        labels: [],
        datasets: [{
        label: 'My First dataset',
        backgroundColor: [
            'rgb(22,83,126)',
            'rgb(188,160,85)',
            'rgb(61,133,198)',
            'rgb(130,57,69)',
            'rgb(249,203,156)',
            'rgb(242,235,236)',
            'rgb(224,102,102)',
            'rgb(57,130,118)',
        ],
        borderColor: 'rgb(0, 0, 0)',
        data: [],
        }]
      },
      options: {
            animations: {
            tension: {
                duration: 1000,
                easing: 'linear',
                from: 1,
                to: 0,
                loop: true
                }
            }
        }
    };

    const artChart = new Chart(
    document.getElementById('artChart').getContext("2d"),
    config,
    );
```

My select:

```
<div class="form-group">
     <select name="departamento" class="form-control js-departamento" id="departamento" name="departamento">
             {{--Construimos las opciones con blade--}}
             <option value="">-- Seleccione el Departamento --</option>
             @foreach($arrayDepartamento as $departamentoitem)
                     <option value="{{ $departamentoitem }}">{{ $departamentoitem }}</option>
             @endforeach
     </select>
</div>
```

I was trying to do it through ajax, but it's not really working:

```
<script>
    var dept = $('.js-departamento');

    dept.change(function(event) {

        $.ajax({
            url: "{{ route('get_products_by_department') }}",
            method: 'GET',
            data: {
            departamento: event.target.value,
            },
            success: function addData(artChart, label, data, artdep) {  
                console.log(data);
                for(var i=0; i<7; i++) {
                    artChart.data[i].label.push(label);
                    artChart.data[i].data.push(data);
                }
                        artChart.update();
                    }
                
        });

    });
</script>
```

`console.log(data)` shows:

[image: json]

And the error I'm getting is: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')`

I'd really appreciate some help or guidance

Comment: I think the issue is because you are creating new array for labels and data. I think you should clear them and add new values, using the same instances. I mean  "artChart.data.labels = []; artChart.data.datasets[0].data = [];"

Comment: @user2057925 hi, could you please explain that? I'm kind of confused

Comment: have a look to CHART.JS doc: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html#adding-or-removing-data